# Good, simple software for hand-painting using a graphic pad with pen

Tags: graphics, software-recommendation, graphics-tablet

I like to draw with pen and graphic pad (or with tablets).

For tablets there are a lot of apps for drawing and painting, that go from very simple ones to "full-optional" ones.

For ubuntu I fell the lack of such softwares.

Ok, Gimp is great for manipulating photos and images.
I also found Krita, which is good, and falls in the category "full-optional"
and I tried MyPaint, which is kind of simpler than Krita, and good...

But non of them reaches the usability of the many android apps. Basically my impression is that they are not designed for hand painting via a graphic pad.

So, what software could I try?

Comment: You could try asking your question on Stack Exchange [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions?newreg=644f2ca223894d43a51600e7df318c7d) where I'm sure you will get some responses. Don't forget to mention your platform.

Comment: @David I'm sorry, I was not aware of that policy.

Comment: should I delete my question?

Comment: Please do not it lets others know.

Comment: @David *Hardware* recommendations are off topic, but software recommendations are definitely on topic if they are asking about software for Ubuntu.

Comment: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14394/are-software-recommendations-on-topic-or-not | https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1872/how-to-run-the-software-recommendation-tag